# Magento2 Custom Widget Not Appearing

Tags: php, xml, widget, magento2

I created a module with a Custom Widget. When logging into the admin, going to `content->widgets`, creating an instance, and setting that instance to appear on the homepage, the widget appears as expected.

I have removed this instance and am now trying to create the widget by going to `content->pages`, editing the `homepage -> content` section, and selecting `insert widget`. I created a new instance of the widget and added some additional `text` into the `homepage -> content` section.

When I load the homepage the widget does not appear, though the rest of the `text` does appear.

The block for the widget is being called ( I tested this with a `var_dump` and `exit`).

The template is not being rendered however.

Here is my Block:

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;

class Slider extends Template
{
    protected $_template = "Yamazaki_Slider::widget/slider.phtml";

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory)
    {
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve featured products collection
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('is_featured','1');
    }
}
```

and my Template:

```
<?php $imageBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct'); ?>

<?php foreach($this->getProducts() as $product): ?>
    <?php $productImage = $imageBlock->getImage($product, 'product_page_image_large'); ?>
    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

The other files in my module are:

etc/widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widgets xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Widget:etc/widget.xsd">
<widget id="yamazaki_slider" class="MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider">
    <label translate="true">My Image Slider</label>
    <description>My Image Slider</description>
</widget>
</widgets>
```

module.xml and registration.php.

I do not have a `etc/layout.xml` file as I have noticed some widget/modules contain. Do I need this, or any other files?

Also, If I "Hide the Editor" inside `content->pages->edit->content` I see:

```
<p>{{widget type="MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider"}}</p>`
```

If I replace this with

```
{{block class="MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider" template="widget/slider.phtml"}}
```

The Content appears as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the Block to Render

I had to add `implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface` to  `MyNamespace\Slider\Block\Widget\Slider`.

I'm not sure why this rendered, prior to adding the `implements`, using the first approach and not the second.

Magento is seriously lacking documentation!